# C# Shorten repeated StreamReader

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

The following piece of code reads a .txt file and reads a certain line that starts with the characters declared in the code.

```
 private void rb_point1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string line;

        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(ccpath);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("point01:"))
            {
                message = (line.Split(':')[1]);
                txtb_message.Text = message;
            }
        }
    }
    private void rb_point2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string line;

        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(ccpath);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("point02:"))
            {
                message = (line.Split(':')[1]);
                txtb_message.Text = message;
            }
        }
    }
    private void rb_point3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string line;

        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(ccpath);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("point03:"))
            {
                message = (line.Split(':')[1]);
                txtb_message.Text = message;
            }
        }
    }
    private void rb_point4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string line;

        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(ccpath);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("point04:"))
            {
                message = (line.Split(':')[1]);
                txtb_message.Text = message;
            }
        }
    }
    private void rb_point5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string line;

        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(ccpath);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("point05:"))
            {
                message = (line.Split(':')[1]);
                txtb_message.Text = message;
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue I have is that I have 50 Radio Buttons which means 50 times this code needs repeating. I have no ideas on how to shorten this down or at least make is easier on the eyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first improvement would be a method that does what you want and accepts a parameter for the difference. Like so:

```
private void rb_point1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReadLineAndDisplayText("point01:");
}

private void ReadLineAndDisplayText(string lineStart)
{
    string line;

    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(ccpath);
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith(lineStart))
        {
            message = (line.Split(':')[1]);
            txtb_message.Text = message;
        }
    }
}
```

Like that you already get rid of most duplication.

Next is to not have a new `rb_point1_CheckedChanged()` method for each radio button, but assign the same method to all of the buttons. You can then use `sender` to identify the radio button that was pressed. In the designer, you can e.g. assign the `Tag`, so your code is like this:

```
private void anyRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton radio = (RadioButton) sender;
    string lineStart = (string) radio.Tag;
    ReadLineAndDisplayText(lineStart);
}
```

Like that you'll end up with only 2 methods.